# How do I iterate over just the odd numbered xml node attributes using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

So I am trying to iterate over only the odd numbered nodes in the xml file.  the node named  where x is the  value of the input from 1 to 32.

```
Option Explicit

Dim xmlDoc, i, colNodes, objNode
Set xmlDoc = _
  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("C:\Scripts\_setup.xml")


Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes("//input") 

For Each objNode in colNodes

   objNode.selectSingleNode("off_text").text = "me!"
   objNode.selectSingleNode("on_text").text = "you!"

   End If

Next

xmlDoc.Save "C:\Scripts\_setup.xml"
```

Comment: the node name with attribute is input id='x' in xml, where x is a value between 1 and 32

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your for loop to this:

```
intCount = colNodes.Length
For i=0 to intCount-1 step 2
   colNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode("off_text").text = "me!"
   colNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode("on_text").text = "you!"
Next
```

So, only nodes 0,2,4,6.....30 are selected which have the attribute values 'id' = 1,3,5,7.....31(**odd numbered** as you needed)

Another way of doing it is:

```
Set colNodes = oxml.selectnodes("//input")
intCtr = colNodes.length
For i=1 To intCtr
    If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
        Set tempNode = oxml.selectsinglenode("//input[@id='"&i&"']")
        tempNode.selectsinglenode("off_text").text = "me!"
        tempNode.selectsinglenode("on_text").text = "you!"
    End If
Next
```